# How to Embed HTML in a PHP Wordpress Navigation?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, navigation

My wordpress navigation code is as follows:

```
<?php } ?>
<?php if (get_option('fudge_speakers_widget_menu')) { ?>
<li><a title="<?php echo get_option('fudge_speakers_widget_menu'); ?>" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>#speakers"><?php echo get_option('fudge_speakers_widget_menu'); ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
<?php if (get_option('fudge_sponsors_widget_menu')) { ?>
<li><a title="<?php echo get_option('fudge_sponsors_widget_menu'); ?>" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>#sponsors"><?php echo get_option('fudge_sponsors_widget_menu'); ?></a></li>
```

I need to add in a separate page that is not from a widget. Just www.example.com. I tried `<li>www.example.com</li>` but that failed.

How do I add the external widgetless nav-link in the PHP file?

I don't know if it helps, but this is using the [Fudge theme](http://www.eventmanagerblog.com/conference-wordpress-theme-fudge)

Comment: you should post your question at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: When you say it failed, what happened? Did the link show up at all?

Answer (score 0):

```
<li>
```

is not a link but a list entry.

```
<a href="www.example.com">Click Me!</a>
```

would be a link.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: If I did not misunderstand the question, yes this answers it. For a link, use a href, not li.

Answer (score 0):

For `www.example.com` to appear on the `li` list, you will need to change

```
<li>www.example.com</li>
```

to

```
<li><a href="www.example.com">www.example.com</a></li>
```

The second `www.example.com` can be change to whatever text you want displayed